# EMS SQL manager permission problem

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, permissions

I have a strange problem with EMS SQL Manager.

I'm using MySQL 5.5 with linux servers. One of my developers need to edit store procedure, so I grant him:

```
GRANT CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON `testdb`.* TO 'testuser'@'192.168.13.11'
```

When he clicked edit store in EMS SQL Manager, what he got is:

```
SELECT command denied to user 'testuser'@'192.168.13.11' for table 'user'
```

I find out that EMS SQL Manager ask for select privilege in some tables, so I need to grant this user some extra permissions.

```
GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`user` TO 'testuser'@'192.168.13.11';
GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`db` TO 'testuser'@'192.168.13.11';
GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`tables_priv` TO 'testuser'@'192.168.13.11';
GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`columns_priv` TO 'testuser'@'192.168.13.11';
GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`procs_priv` TO 'testuser'@'192.168.13.11';
```

So my question is, WHY EMS SQL Manager need those privileges?
I can create, drop procedure in mysql command line client without problem.

**Update**

After some investigation, I still do not understand EMS SQL Manager.
This is the action EMS SQL Manager take when click the `Compile` button.

```
Executed  : 5/8/2013 3:10:40 PM
Operation : CONNECT
Result    : "OK."

Executed  : 5/8/2013 3:10:40 PM
Operation : show variables like 'character_set_results'
Result    : "OK."

Executed  : 5/8/2013 3:10:40 PM
Operation : SELECT * FROM mysql.user ORDER BY User, Host
Result    : "SELECT command denied to user 'ems'@'192.168.13.11' for table
'user'"

Executed  : 5/8/2013 3:10:40 PM
Operation : DISCONNECT
Result    : "OK."

Executed  : 5/8/2013 3:10:41 PM
Operation : select p.`db`, p.`name`, p.`type`, p.`specific_name`,
p.`language`, p.`sql_data_access`, p.`is_deterministic`, p.`security_type`,
p.`param_list`, p.`returns`, p.`body`, p.`definer`, p.`created`,
p.`modified`, p.`sql_mode`, p.`comment` from `mysql`.`proc` as p where
p.`type` = 'PROCEDURE' and p.`db`='reportingdb' and
p.`name`='100_rpt_campaign_ip'
Result    : "OK."

Executed  : 5/8/2013 3:10:41 PM
Operation : SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE `reportingdb`.`100_rpt_campaign_ip`
Result    : "OK."
```

So my question, **What is the `Compile` button trying to do?** Why does it want to select `mysql.user`? I think that editing a stored procedure is two steps of drop and re create it, why does it want to do more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing you can do to understand this behaviour better is to *ask the software vendor*. If you don't want to grant those permissions, lodging a bug report might be appropriate.

I'm going to hazard a guess that EMS SQL Manager is trying to be too clever, and check whether you have `Alter_routine_priv` or `Create_routine_priv` so that it can return a warning or error before it tries sending your `ALTER ROUTINE` to the database.

Most SQL Editors run lots of queries in the background to support "IntelliSense", speed up common queries, or provide background information, and a lot of the time they just don't make any sense (some of them are downright frightening).

Answer (score 2):

When someone has the clearance to call a stored procedure, the grants for the user who called the stored procedure must be checked.

Here is the description of `mysql.proc`:

```
+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field                | Type                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| db                   | char(64)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | NO   | PRI |                     |                             |
| name                 | char(64)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | NO   | PRI |                     |                             |
| type                 | enum('FUNCTION','PROCEDURE')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        | NO   | PRI | NULL                |                             |
| specific_name        | char(64)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | NO   |     |                     |                             |
| language             | enum('SQL')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         | NO   |     | SQL                 |                             |
| sql_data_access      | enum('CONTAINS_SQL','NO_SQL','READS_SQL_DATA','MODIFIES_SQL_DATA')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  | NO   |     | CONTAINS_SQL        |                             |
| is_deterministic     | enum('YES','NO')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    | NO   |     | NO                  |                             |
| security_type        | enum('INVOKER','DEFINER')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | NO   |     | DEFINER             |                             |
| param_list           | blob                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| returns              | longblob                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| body                 | longblob                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| definer              | char(77)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | NO   |     |                     |                             |
| created              | timestamp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| modified             | timestamp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
| sql_mode             | set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','NOT_USED','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVALID_DATES','ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO','TRADITIONAL','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION','PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH') | NO   |     |                     |                             |
| comment              | char(64)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | NO   |     |                     |                             |
| character_set_client | char(32)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| collation_connection | char(32)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| db_collation         | char(32)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| body_utf8            | longblob                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
20 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Notice column #8 : `security_type`. Its data type is `enum('INVOKER','DEFINER')`.

Also, notice column #12 : `definer`

What do these settings tell me about the stored procedure's usage?

- `INVOKER` : If you call the stored procedure, the authenticated user must have all the necessary grants before accessing the databases, tables and columns referenced in the stored procedure. For example, suppose `root@localhost` created a stored procedure called `GetData` and sets `security_type` as `INVOKER`. If user `testuser@'192.168.13.11'` calls `GetData`, mysqld will look at every database, table and column in the stored procedure and verify that `testuser@'192.168.13.11'` has the necessary grants to fully execute every SQL command in the stored procedure.
- `DEFINER` : If you call the stored procedure, the authenticated user effectively 'borrows' the grants of the user who created the stored procedure. The creator is defined in `definer`. For example, suppose `root@localhost` created a stored procedure called `GetData` and sets `security_type` as `DEFINER`. If user `testuser@'192.168.13.11'` calls `GetData`, mysqld will assume `root@localhost` is the caller of `GetData`. All checks for grants will quickly pass and `GetData` runs as if `root@localhost` called it. It's as if mysqld becomes a stored procedure proxy once it sees `DEFINER`.

Compare the aforementioned info to the [MySQL Documentation on Creating Procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html)

> The SQL SECURITY characteristic can be DEFINER or INVOKER to specify the security context; that is, whether the routine executes using the privileges of the account named in the routine DEFINER clause or the user who invokes it. This account must have permission to access the database with which the routine is associated. The default value is DEFINER. The user who invokes the routine must have the EXECUTE privilege for it, as must the DEFINER account if the routine executes in definer security context.
>
> The DEFINER clause specifies the MySQL account to be used when checking access privileges at routine execution time for routines that have the SQL SECURITY DEFINER characteristic.
>   This rigorous check is performed quickly because all the grant tables are loaded in RAM upon mysqld's startup. Obviously, a stored procedure with security_type `INVOKER` is more strict in allowing an authenticated user access to queries within the code.

This rigorous check is performed quickly because all the grant tables are loaded in RAM upon mysqld's startup. Obviously, a stored procedure with security_type `INVOKER` is more strict in allowing an authenticated user access to queries within the code.

## UPDATE 2013-05-08 11:29 EDT

Please look at the EMS output

```
Executed  : 5/8/2013 3:10:40 PM
Operation : SELECT * FROM mysql.user ORDER BY User, Host
Result    : "SELECT command denied to user 'ems'@'192.168.13.11' for table 'user'"
```

Who is trying to connect? `ems'@'192.168.13.11'`

Does this user exist? Try running the following:

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

What do these functions give you:

- [USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user) reports how you attempted to authenticate in MySQL
- [CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) reports how you were allowed to authenticate in MySQL

The second function is what you want to give privileges to.

In your particular case, my guess is that `ems'@'192.168.13.11'` does not exist and you would need to run one of the following:

```
GRANT CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON *.* TO 'ems'@'192.168.13.11';
GRANT CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON *.* TO 'ems'@'192.168.13.%';
GRANT CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON *.* TO 'ems'@'%'; -- usually not recommended
```

What will these commands do?

- `GRANT CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON *.* TO 'ems'@'192.168.13.11';` will allow the `ems` access to editing all stored procedures if and only `ems` logged into MySQL from `192.168.13.11`
- `GRANT CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON *.* TO 'ems'@'192.168.13.%';` will allow the `ems` access to editing all stored procedures if and only `ems` logged into MySQL from `192.168.13.%` netblock
- `GRANT CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON *.* TO 'ems'@'%';` will allow the `ems` access to editing all stored procedures if and only `ems` logged into MySQL from anywhere.  This one is normally not recommended since this allows `ems` remote connections and if port 3306 is world accessible.

Now look back at your original `GRANT`

```
GRANT CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON `testdb`.* TO 'testuser'@'192.168.13.11';
```

User `testuser` can only access the `testdb` if and only if `testuser` is authenticating from `'192.168.13.11'`. If you want `testuser` to access other another user's stored procedures, thenyou need to run this:

```
GRANT CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON *.* TO 'testuser'@'192.168.13.11';
```

Please, Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my question a bit. I do not see the relationship between your answer to my problem. All I want to do is editing a stored procedure? Why EMS SQL Manager need those permissions? You can see my new update for more information.