# What are definer and invoker rights in database, Oracle and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, oracle

What are definer and invoker rights in database, Oracle and MySQL? I just don't get it.

Comment: Check out this link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/network.121/e17607/dr_ir.htm#DBSEG659

Comment: In Oracle the definer rights (default) are something like suid bit in Unix. The procedure is executed with privs of it's owner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's take a simple example:

You have this procedure using "definer rights" - which is the default in Oracle.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DEL_EMP AS
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM EMP;
END;
```

Another user who calls this procedure only needs `EXECUTE` privilege for this procedure, it is not required that such user has `DELETE` privilege on table EMP.

Procedure runs under permission of the procedure owner (or user who *defined* it, thus it is called "definer" rights).

"Inovker Rights" is the opposite. A user who likes to runs this procedure successfully must have `EXECUTE` privilege for this procedure **and** `DELETE` privilege for table EMP.

There are some more points regarding definer and invoker rights but for a general understanding this should be enough.

Comment: How to invoke the sql invoker mode? I believe it is the definer mode which gets invoked by default...

Comment: You must declare it in the procedure `CREATE PROCEDURE DEL_EMP AUTHID CURRENT_USER AS ...`

Answer (score 3):

## MySQL Perspective

The DEFINER and INVOKER rights (a.k.a. the `SQL SECURITY`) signify how mysqld looks at requests for and anticipates what the mysql user is calling for :

- Query
- View
- Stored Procedure ([See MySQL Documentation on this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-programs-security.html))

as well as if the mysql user has all necessary rights to the following:

- The query's underlying tables
- The view's underlying tables
- The stored procedure's underlying tables
- [**EXECUTE privilege**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_execute) for the stored procedure

I have addressed this question in the past

- `Jun 12, 2013` : [MySQL: Securing Access using Stored Procedures](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44366/mysql-securing-access-using-stored-procedures/44371#44371)
- `Apr 08, 2013` : [Why does this procedure raise a privilege error?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39492/why-does-this-procedure-raise-a-privilege-error/39499#39499)
- `Mar 08, 2013` : [EMS SQL manager permission problem](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36233/ems-sql-manager-permission-problem/36279#36279)
- `Mar 23, 2012` : [MySQL Views Authorization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11381/mysql-views-authorization/15489#15489)